# Where/how to define a common object property used in different ontologies

Tags: owl, ontology

I'm developing an ontology but I have different parts in different files with different URIs, all starting with `http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/`.

I have defined `partOf` the way it's described [here](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/BestPractices/OEP/SimplePartWhole/) and right now it looks like this:

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula#partOf">
  <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#topObjectProperty"/>
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#TransitiveProperty"/>
  <rdfs:comment xml:lang="es">Indica la composición entre individuos</rdfs:comment>
  <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">Represents part-whole relations</rdfs:comment>
  <rdfs:label xml:lang="es">parteDe</rdfs:label>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

But I have noticed I want to use it different parts, where it doesn't make sense to import `curricula` since all I need is `partOf`.

Is there a standard way of dealing with this or should I just create a new file and move this object property there and import it when need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to have an ontology with these properties and classes and import it where required - OWL does not support importing just part of an ontology, at the moment.